# Error in running a Hello World app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity

I created a blank template and chose API 15 as minimum.

1- The `activity_main.xml` preview asked me to choose another theme. Why?
2- The `MainActivity.java` class is extending `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`. I tried to delete it and typed `Activity` and imported the corresponding jar but then the IDE doesn't reconize `R` in `R.layout.activity_main`. The IDE says it can't resolve `AppCompatActivity`in import section of the code. Where is the problem?
[image: MainActivity]

```
package com.company.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks
P.S.
It seems the gradle was somehow unsuccessful in building the project. I'd used -Xmx256m in its settings.(What was the problem with this curb?) I removed the curb and it built the project. The weird thing is Android Studio recognized AppCompat stuff after building the project! (Shouldn't the IDE know all the classes used in code before compile?). Anyway, my problem is solved now but I don't know the reason

Comment: I'm going to need more data like the code for starters, the problem could be in a couple of places. Also ignore the Android Studio Graphic XML editor, it can't preview 80% of the custom themes

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having that error then you can try going step by step via this blog : [Hello World App on android studio](http://www.android10001tips.com/hello-world-app-on-android-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you uploaded your code

Answer (score 0):

If the error is Cannot resolve `R` you just need to press `ctrl`+`shift`+`o` to organize imports and restart android studio